# Find the solution set to the equation: $3x-6y = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the solution set to a basic equation:
$$3x - 6y = 0$$
I solved for $x$ and $y$:
\begin{align}
x &= 2y\\
y &= \tfrac12x
\end{align}
So the solution set is:
$$\{2y, \tfrac12x\}$$
I checked my answer and the solution manual shows the answer as: $\{2t,t\}$

I'm not sure how they arrived at this answer.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$ for objects? Reals?

Comment: @sigmabe It's not specified, I would assume real numbers yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the solution set in various ways. The solution set is
$$\begin{array} \{\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x=2y\}&=&\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=x/2\}\\&=&\{(2t,t)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid t\in \mathbb{R}\}\\&=&\{(s,s/2)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid s\in \mathbb{R}\}\end{array}$$

Comment: Ah ok, so I was in fact right and just got an answer different than the solution manual. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't say you were right. The solution set must be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you must specify the relation beween $x$ and $y$! Also the answer in the manual isn't correct...